# "come" in "become" (English) vs "venir" in "devenir" (French)

Tags: english, etymology, french

In both French and English, the word for become (devenir) includes the word for come (venir), even though the etymologies and words are very different. Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Old English “becomen” actually means “come, arrive”. It takes on the meaning “come to be” in Middle English (the OED has references for this meaning from about the end of the 12th century onwards). It is possible that this shift in meaning was at least influenced by French devenir.

Comment: This seems similar to some of the uses of Spanish _llegar_ 'arrive'; it gets used in many inchoative constructions. English also has the inchoative construction _come to be_ = _become_, with almost identical syntax, as well as the various inchoative uses of _get_ for both _be_ and _have_; i.e, _get_ means either _come to be_ or _come to have_, which is why American English uses _got_ to mean possessive _have_ -- _Got a match?_